# how to put in the same (label ) text line: input ? image

Tags: html, css

I would like both the label and input on line, not like in image. Can you suggest me what is the problem in this html code? How to fix my problem?

I have this code html:

```
<div class="contant">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s4">
        <label for="invoice_number">Number:</label>
        <input formControlName="invoice_number" id="invoice_number" type="text" class="validate">
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s4">
        <div class="row">
          <label for="invoice_date">Date:</label>
          <input formControlName="invoice_date" id="invoice_date" type="date" class="datepicker" materialize="pickadate" [materializeParams]="[{ format: 'yyyy-mm-dd', formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
          closeOnSelect: true, selectMonths: true, selectYears: true, today: '',
          max: true, onSet: onSetDatepicker }]">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s4">
        <p style="text-align: center; color:black">Some Data</p>
        <div class="input-field col s2">
          <label for="client_id">First Last Name:</label>
          <input formControlName="client_id" id="client_id" type="text" class="validate">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="input-field col s2">
          <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
          <input formControlName="phone" id="phone" type="text" class="validate">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="input-field col s2">
          <label for="add">Add:</label>
          <input formControlName="add" id="add" type="text" class="validate">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This code display this photo:

[image]

Css

```
    label {
      width:180px;
      clear:left;
      text-align:left;
      padding-left:1.5px;
  }
```

I want to show this image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should add to label `position: absolute;` and add to input `border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(117, 117, 117);` and of course to set suitable padding

Comment: Yes, but don't change nothing. Thnx

Comment: Css code  `.contant {
    width: 1200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
.input-field {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.input-field input {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px 2px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.input-field label {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.s2 input {
    width: 20px;
}
#phone {
    margin-left: 60px;
}
#add {
    margin-left: 100px;
}`

Comment: try this in your code